# select field not included in group by list

Tags: database, oracle, group-by

I have following oracle query :

```
SELECT distinct  DM.name,
    ND.param5 ,
    ND.param4 ,  
      DECODE(ND.param3, 'TRS01','Mark for Return to warehouse',
'TRS02','Waiting for distributor approval on return',
'TRS03','Waiting for Service Provider approval on return',
'TRS04','Return to Distributor',
'TRS05','Return to Warehouse',
'TRS06','Mark for Return to Distributor',
'TRS08','Quarantined',
'TRS10' ,'New',
'TRS11','Waiting for Distributor acceptance',
'TRS12' ,'Moved to distributor warehouse',
'TRS13','Waiting for reseller acceptance',
'TRS14','Moved to reseller warehouse',
'TRS15','In-Use', 
'TRS16','Returned',
'TRS17','Deattached',
'TRS18','Sold'),   NS.name ,
    COUNT( distinct ND.NUMBERDETAILID) serialcount,ND.param3,'ALL',
   FROM ndetail ND,
    nbatch NB,
    nstatus NS,
    dynamicmaster DM,(select his.createdate,h.numberdetailid,his.numberstatusid,his.param3,his.actualnumber 
from ndetailhistory his,
(select max(createdate) createdate,numberdetailid 
from ndetailhistory 
group by numberdetailid) h 
where h.numberdetailid = his.numberdetailid
and h.createdate = his.createdate) NDH
  WHERE ND.numberbatchid = NB.numberbatchid
  AND NS.numberstatusid  = ND.numberstatusid
  and DM.DYNAMICMASTERID = NB.WAREHOUSEID
  and NDH.actualnumber = ND.actualnumber
  and ND.NUMBERDETAILID = NDH.NUMBERDETAILID
  and NB.numbergroupid = (select numbergroupid from ngroup where alias = 'TEST')
  AND (case when 'ALL'='ALL' THEN '1' ELSE  ND.PARAM3 END ) =(case when 'ALL'='ALL' THEN '1' ELSE  'ALL' END )
  GROUP BY DM.name,ND.param5,ND.param4,ND.param3,NS.name
order by 1,3,2
```

I want createdate also in select list but not want to group by with createdate.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use GROUP BY a field from the SELECT list have to be in the GROUP BY statement or in an aggregate function. So if you don't want to include it into the GROUP BY just add for example **MAX(createdate)** to the SELECT list.

Answer (score 0):

All non-aggregate columns in the select-list must be listed in the GROUP BY clause.  The DECODE in the main select-list doesn't (yet) have an alias, either, which make it unduly hard.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DM.name,
       ND.param5,
       ND.param4,  
       DECODE(ND.param3, 'TRS01','Mark for Return to warehouse',
                         'TRS02','Waiting for distributor approval on return',
                         'TRS03','Waiting for Service Provider approval on return',
                         'TRS04','Return to Distributor',
                         'TRS05','Return to Warehouse',
                         'TRS06','Mark for Return to Distributor',
                         'TRS08','Quarantined',
                         'TRS10' ,'New',
                         'TRS11','Waiting for Distributor acceptance',
                         'TRS12' ,'Moved to distributor warehouse',
                         'TRS13','Waiting for reseller acceptance',
                         'TRS14','Moved to reseller warehouse',
                         'TRS15','In-Use', 
                         'TRS16','Returned',
                         'TRS17','Deattached',
                         'TRS18','Sold')
       decoded_param3,
       NS.name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ND.NUMBERDETAILID) serialcount,
       ND.param3,
       'ALL' all_code
  FROM ndetail ND,
       nbatch NB,
       nstatus NS,
       dynamicmaster DM,
       (SELECT his.createdate, h.numberdetailid, his.numberstatusid, his.param3,
               his.actualnumber 
          FROM ndetailhistory his,
               (SELECT MAX(createdate) createdate, numberdetailid 
                  FROM ndetailhistory 
                 GROUP BY numberdetailid) h 
         WHERE h.numberdetailid = his.numberdetailid
           AND h.createdate = his.createdate) NDH
 WHERE ND.numberbatchid   = NB.numberbatchid
   AND NS.numberstatusid  = ND.numberstatusid
   AND DM.DYNAMICMASTERID = NB.WAREHOUSEID
   AND NDH.actualnumber   = ND.actualnumber
   AND ND.NUMBERDETAILID  = NDH.NUMBERDETAILID
   AND NB.numbergroupid  = (SELECT numbergroupid FROM ngroup WHERE alias = 'TEST')
   AND (CASE WHEN 'ALL'='ALL' THEN '1' ELSE ND.PARAM3 END) =
       (CASE WHEN 'ALL'='ALL' THEN '1' ELSE 'ALL'     END)
 GROUP BY DM.name, ND.param5, ND.param4, decoded_param3, NS.name, ND.param3, all_code
 ORDER BY 1,3,2
```

You should learn about these fabulous things called 'tables' which allow you to store information for DECODE operations such as the ND.param3 lookup in the database, rather than writing the tables out longhand (and variously) in different queries.

You should also learn about explicit JOIN queries and use them.